# What's the Point of the prefix ? operator in Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, operators

I'm just wondering what applications it has. I believe in 1.9 the prefix ? would return the string version of that character.

```
?a   #=> "a"
?\t  #=> "\t"
```

Is this just  shorthand for 'a' or '\t'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's mainly for backwards compatibility. In versions prior to 1.9, `?` evaluated to a `Fixnum` corresponding to the ASCII value of the character in question. Indexing into a `String` *also* returned a `Fixnum`.

So, if you wanted to check, for example, if the third character of a string was the letter 'a' you would do

```
s[2] == ?a
```

In Ruby 1.9, strings are no longer treated as an array of fixnums but as an iterator of characters (single-character strings, actually). As a result, the above code would no longer work: `s[2]` would be a string, `?a` would be a number, and those two would never be equal.

Therefore, `?` was also changed to evaluate to a single-character string, so that the above code continues to work.

Answer (score 2):

in ruby 1.8 and earlier

```
?a
```

would return the ASCII version of 'a' char.

in 1.9 it just returns the string ( just as you've assumed )

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, you get the string value of the characters.  It was previously used to get the ASCII value of the characters.